# UPDATE from CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am updating a table from the result of a self join via a CTE. When doing a select to view the expected results of the update it is able to return the results in 16 seconds.

However, when I then use the same syntax to try to actually update the underlying table, it is excruciatingly slow.

For the life of me I cannot figure out why such a dramatic slowdown. I frequently update tables via CTE and it is usually adequetely fast and reasonable compared to the equivalent select.

I have tried both with and without a PrimaryKey/Clustered index on the underlying table and it makes no difference.

The join is on a calculated column so cannot be indexed.

If the difference in time between the SELECT and the UPDATE was say double then it wouldn't be a concern. The problem here is the sheer magnitude of the time increase when going from the select to the update. 16 seconds for the select with a result of 1323 rows, to update just 2 of those rows takes 59 seconds, to update 4 takes 1 min 19 seconds and to update 6 takes 1 min 39 seconds (so it seems each additional row adds 10 seconds).

Can anybody shed some light on this for me and suggest a way to speed this up?

Here's the sample code:

```
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT
                DENSE_RANK() OVER (Order by
                                col1,
                                col2,
                                col3) SetID,                
                COUNT(*) OVER (partition by
                                col1,
                                col2,
                                col3) DupsInSet,
                row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY
                                col1,
                                col2,
                                col3
                                ORDER BY                                    
                                col4 desc) RowInSet,
                COUNT(col4) OVER (partition by
                                col1,
                                col2,
                                col3) NonNull,
                *
            FROM mytable)
```

--The following completes in 16 seconds and returns 1323 rows

```
    select b.col4,a.*

    from cte a
    join cte b on b.SetID=a.SetID

    where a.DupsInSet>1
    and a.NonNull>0
    and b.RowInSet=1
    and a.RowInSet>1
    and b.col4 is not null
    and a.col4 is null
```

--Updating from this runs for so long that I didn't even let it finish
--As a test I limited the update to the Top 2. This then took 59 seconds just to update 2 rows

```
    UPDATE TOP(2) a

    SET a.col4=b.col4

    from cte a
    join cte b on b.SetID=a.SetID

    where a.DupsInSet>1
    and a.NonNull>0
    and b.RowInSet=1
    and a.RowInSet>1
    and b.col4 is not null
    and a.col4 is null
```

Actual Execution Plan for SELECT https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=ByItSnhuW

Actual Execution Plan for UPDATE https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Ske_In3_Z

**UPDATE:**

Taking the suggestion from SqlZim it ran for over 4 minutes without finishing at which point i stopped it.

However, with

1. a change in the schema (thank you SqlZim) from several VARCHAR(MAX) columns down to VARCHAR(?) where ? is the max(len(column))

and

2. some modifications to SqlZims suggested query, the update was able to run in 23 seconds!...which is approximately 3,300 times faster :)

Here is the final query (unless someone can make it work without having to list all the darn columns e.g. joining on the SetID):

(note, the CTE is still used to filter the original table down from its 600k+ rows)

```
;WITH CTE AS (SELECT                             
                COUNT(*) OVER (partition by
                                [col1]
                              ,[col2]
                              ,[col3]
                              ,[col4]
                              ,[col5]
                              ,[col6]
                              ,[col7]
                              ,[col8]
                              ,[col9]
                              ,[col10]
                              ,[col11]
                              ,[col12]
                              ,[col13]
                              ,[col14]
                              ,[col15]
                              ,[col16]
                              ,[col17]
                              ,[col18]
                              ,[col19]
                              ,[col20]
                              ,[col21]
                              ,[col22]
                              ,[col23]) DupsInSet,
                COUNT(col24) OVER (partition by
                                [col1]
                              ,[col2]
                              ,[col3]
                              ,[col4]
                              ,[col5]
                              ,[col6]
                              ,[col7]
                              ,[col8]
                              ,[col9]
                              ,[col10]
                              ,[col11]
                              ,[col12]
                              ,[col13]
                              ,[col14]
                              ,[col15]
                              ,[col16]
                              ,[col17]
                              ,[col18]
                              ,[col19]
                              ,[col20]
                              ,[col21]
                              ,[col22]
                              ,[col23]) NonNull,
                *
            FROM mytable
    )

update a
  set a.col24 = b.col24
from cte a
  cross apply (
    select top 1 i.col24
    from cte i
    where (i.col1=a.col1 OR (i.col1 is null AND a.col1 is null))
         and (i.col2=a.col2 OR (i.col2 is null AND a.col2 is null))
         and (i.col3=a.col3 OR (i.col3 is null AND a.col3 is null))
         and (i.col4=a.col4 OR (i.col4 is null AND a.col4 is null))
         and (i.col5=a.col5 OR (i.col5 is null AND a.col5 is null))
         and (i.col6=a.col6 OR (i.col6 is null AND a.col6 is null))
         and (i.col7=a.col7 OR (i.col7 is null AND a.col7 is null))
         and (i.col8=a.col8 OR (i.col8 is null AND a.col8 is null))
         and (i.col9=a.col9 OR (i.col9 is null AND a.col9 is null))
         and (i.col10=a.col10 OR (i.col10 is null AND a.col10 is null))
         and (i.col11=a.col11 OR (i.col11 is null AND a.col11 is null))
         and (i.col12=a.col12 OR (i.col12 is null AND a.col12 is null))
         and (i.col13=a.col13 OR (i.col13 is null AND a.col13 is null))
         and (i.col14=a.col14 OR (i.col14 is null AND a.col14 is null))
         and (i.col15=a.col15 OR (i.col15 is null AND a.col15 is null))
         and (i.col16=a.col16 OR (i.col16 is null AND a.col16 is null))
         and (i.col17=a.col17 OR (i.col17 is null AND a.col17 is null))
         and (i.col18=a.col18 OR (i.col18 is null AND a.col18 is null))
         and (i.col19=a.col19 OR (i.col19 is null AND a.col19 is null))
         and (i.col20=a.col20 OR (i.col20 is null AND a.col20 is null))
         and (i.col21=a.col21 OR (i.col21 is null AND a.col21 is null))
         and (i.col22=a.col22 OR (i.col22 is null AND a.col22 is null))
         and (i.col23=a.col23 OR (i.col23 is null AND a.col23 is null))
        and i.col24 is not null
    order by col24 desc
  ) b
where a.col24 is null
and a.DupsInSet>1
and a.NonNull>0
```

Comment: Share your execution plans using [Paste The Plan @ brentozar.com](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/) here are the instructions: [How to Use Paste the Plan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/instructions/). Sample data and desired results would help too.

Comment: @SqlZim - edited posted to add links to execution plans. Link to sample rows from the select https://ibb.co/huyQhQ

Comment: Why are you updating the CTE from the CTE?  What is the point of that since it is only available in the first statement after the CTE is is created?

Comment: How well does SQLZims solution perform, is it much faster? Looking at those plans I'd have a hard time believing the issue was your query, but I don't know how well Paste the Plan translates actual plans. I would look for blocking on your server, where another process is holding a lock on the table you want to update and the time spent is your waiting for a lock. Also notice that the first plan is a parallel plan while the second is serial, that would make a difference in performance on your server.

Comment: @HLGEM - the task is to copy data from one row to another using specific columns, i.e. within the same table, thus CTE to CTE

Comment: After seeing the 23 columns in the actual ranking/window functions...Are they all necessary? Is there no smaller set of columns to determine a `SetId`? It also shows that your est. row size is 72502 bytes. That seems pretty wide... What does your table schema look like?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you want to update `col4` where it is `null` from rows that match on `col1, col2, col3`, and you want to use the first non `null` value of `col4` based on `col4 desc`.

You could do that like so:

```
update a
  set a.col4 = b.col4
from mytable a
  cross apply (
    select top 1 i.col4
    from mytable i
    where i.col1 = a.col1
      and i.col2 = a.col2
      and i.col3 = a.col3
      and i.col4 is not null
    order by col4 desc
  ) b
where a.col4 is null
```

You could also support this operation with a supporting index, e.g.:

```
create nonclustered index ix_mytable_col1_col2_col3_inc_col4
  on dbo.mytable (col1,col2,col3) 
    include (col4);
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this will work to get the update done. However, I was hoping to find a way to speed up the CTE version as the real job that I'm working on requires lots of manipulations like this across the data and it is much easier having a CTE to refer to. I'm going to leave it out there for a while and see what people come up with. If nothing better comes along in a day or so then I will mark your response as being the answer.

Comment: Why not use a #temp table instead of a CTE? You can index a #temp table and reference it in multiple steps.

Comment: @HLGEM - because the columns used in the calculation of the 4 calculated columns change throughout the process (and there are 25 columns involved in total). Thus, I would need to either create a new temp table each time or update the 4 calculated columns. With the CTE i can simply make a few quick edits by commenting out/in the necessary columns. However, as it stands right now, due to the excessive time it is taking for updates using this method, the temp table may be a worthwhile solution.